# Adding values to a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to add an array of values to an array in an object but for some reason, the structure doesn't look right.

I start with the empty object:

```
var title = "name";
var kw = "fashion";

objectName = {[title]: [] };
```

I then push a string into the array:

```
objectName[title].push(kw);
```

However, when I `console.log` `objectName`, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

I would like to have the following structure instead:

```
{"name":["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]}
```

Am I building the array incorrectly? I'm just confused as to why the property name (utm_term [assisting]) appears under the array as well.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with JSON. JSON is a textual notation for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Is the property in the object supposed to be called `title` or `name` (or `utm_term`, or `assisting`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is supposed to be called `name` (the *value* of `title`), then your code would be fine in ES2015+ (the new JavaScript standard from June), but you're probably using it in ES5 or earlier as that's what most JavaScript engines currently support.

In that case, you need to break your `objectName` initialization into two parts:

```
objectName = {};
objectName[title] = [];
```

E.g.:

```js
var title = "name";
var kw = "fashion";

var objectName = {};
objectName[title] = [];

objectName[title].push(kw);

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(objectName, null, 2)); // Just using JSON for output display
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

(I assume you've declared the `objectName` variable somewhere. If not, be sure to add the `var` I added above, otherwise you fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)